# How to make blur event occur on every looped table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table with dynamic looped row and inside it there is seven static table data(td) and this table data inside there is input box. So I wanted to get the input value of each table data input using blur event(jquery).

Here is my php code which loop the table row

```
<table =”mytable”>
<?php foreach ($vendors_details as  $value) { ?>

   <tr class="temp">(

       <td class="magazineid"><?php echo $value->magazine_name; ?></td>
       <td class="allocated"><input type="text" id="disabledInput" name="allocate[]"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->allocate;?>" disabled></td>
             <td class="add"><input type="text" name="add"  placeholder="add" class="form-control added" required></td>
             <td class="less"><input type="text" name="less[]" id="less"  class="form-control" required></td>
             <td class="returned"><input type="text" name="return[]" id="return"  class="form-control" required></td>
             <td class="paided"><input type="text" name="paid[]"  class="form-control" required></td>
             <td class="amounted"><strong><input type="text" id="amount" value="<?php echo $value->Amount;?>" disabled></strong></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="magazine_id[]" id="magazine_id" value="<?php echo $value->magazine_id; ?>" hidden ></td>

           </tr>
</table>
```

here are my scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".added",function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("hasadded")){
            $("#mytable").find("tr.temp").each(function(index){

                $(".added").blur(function(){
                    var userinput = $(".added").val();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        console.log(userinput);
                    });
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

on myscript I have trying to get value of table data with class ”added”

it return only the table data of only the first looped table row

please help, I am not much good in jquery

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs in your loop. IDs are supposed to be unique. Are you sure you need them?

Comment: You shouldn't add the `blur` handler inside the `click` handler. You'll get multiple handlers because each time you click you add another handler. Also, I don't see why you're doing it in a `.each` loop, since you're not doing anything with the elements you iterate over. Maybe you mean `$(this).find(".added")`?

Comment: You also have "smart quotes" around the ID in `<table ="mytable">`. HTML doesn't understand this, you have to use ordinary quotes. And you're missing `id=` there, too.

Comment: look, i have that page loaded wvia ajax so to get it the elements i have used click, also as i said i am not good in jquery.

Comment: dont take care of those quotes.in my code i have it right.

Comment: Barmar, what should id do now

Comment: You should do what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#mytable").on("blur", "tr.temp .added:not(.hasadded)", function() {
        var userinput = $(this).val();
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(userinput);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

You don't need to add the `blur` handler inside the `click` handler. Delegating it with `.on` will automatically handle elements that are loaded dynamically using AJAX.

To set a cell to the AJAX response, you can do something like this:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("#mytable").on("blur", "tr.temp .added:not(.hasadded)", function() {
        var userinput = $(this).val();
        var cell7 = $(this).closest("td").siblings().eq(6).find("input");
        $.post("URL", { param: userinput }, function(result) {
            cell7.val(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey, Barmar sorry again, what if i want to get the value of the seventh table cell within that table row and change it to the ajax response.help me i have stacked again.

Comment: any one with the help please!

Comment: i have already the value there at cell7, i want to remove it and set response data

Comment: That's what this does, it replaces the value of an input with the response data.

Comment: It would be better to give it a class name instead of counting cells, so you can do `var cell7 = $(this).closest("td").find(".amount");`

Comment: how can i get you private Sir, i am very new to this jquery

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in becoming a private tutor. You need to study on your own.